# Would it be worth creating an open CL version of my abstract algebra library?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencl, gpu

I'm making an abstract algebra library in Python, and one of the things it does it takes the Cayley table (think of it as an abstract "multiplication" table, which doesn't have to obey the standard rules for multiplication or addition), and uses it to prove whether or not certain identities or properties hold for the binary operator defined by the Cayley table.

The computations for any of these procedures basically boils down to:

1. Use the values in the Cayley table to get the result of some abstract binary operation
2. Compare the resulting values to see if they are equal
3. Do all of the above multiple times in a loop.

This can get very cpu intensive with the sheer number of operations that need to be done, especially if you want to do this for all permutations of cayley tables with size n*n (O(n^2!) for that, I think). The good thing is, this is highly paralelizable, as I have algorithms that can calculate the mth permutation of an n*n cayley table in about O(n) time, and thus the set of all Cayley table permutations can be split near evenly, and multiple processes can be assigned to work on a different subset of the problem in parallel.

Is process like this (replacing values from lookup tables, comparing results) suited to open CL, or any other GPU library for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could change the

```
Compare the resulting values to see if they are equal
```

part to something like

```
subtract one from another, save the result and check for a zero from host side.
```

if the result will decide for just an addition(+) operation, even something looks like

```
subtract one from another, multiply (1-signum(result)) with the adder value, then add.
```

can be faster than cpu. Because gpu memory is generally marginally faster than host memory when read/written in non-random.